# Index in Parquet

Tags: indexing, parquet

I would like to be able to do a fast range query on a Parquet table. The amount of data to be returned is very small compared to the total size but because a full column scan has to be performed it is too slow for my use case.

Using an index would solve this problem and I read that this was to be added in Parquet 2.0. However, I cannot find any other information on this so I am guessing that it was not. I do not think that there would be any fundamental obstacles preventing the addition of (multi-column) indexes, if the data were sorted, which in my case it is.

My question is: when will indexes be added to Parquet, and what would be the high level design for doing so? I think I would already be happy with an index that points out the correct partition.

Kind regards,

Sjoerd.

Comment: A looooong time. It is scheduled for [v2.0](https://github.com/Parquet/parquet-mr).

Comment: maybe interesting for you: https://github.com/lightcopy/parquet-index

Comment: https://blog.cloudera.com/speeding-up-select-queries-with-parquet-page-indexes/

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Parquet currently keeps min/max statistics for each data page. A data page is a group of ~1MB of values (after encoding) for a single column; multiple pages are what make up [Parquet's column chunks](http://ingest.tips/2015/01/31/parquet-row-group-size/).

Those min/max values are used to filter both column chunks and the pages that make up a chunk. So you should be able to improve your query time by sorting records by the columns you want to filter on, then writing the data into Parquet. That way, you get the most out of the stats filtering.

You can also get more granular filtering with this technique by decreasing the page and row group sizes, though you're then trading encoding efficiency and I/O efficiency.

Comment: +1 Great answer. Question though. "You can also get more granular filtering with this technique by decreasing the page and row group sizes" - Are you refering to mapred.max.split.size or something else?

Comment: I'm referring to two Parquet settings: `parquet.block.size` (the target row group size in bytes, default 128MB) and `parquet.page.size` (the target page size in bytes before compression but after encoding, default 1MB).

Comment: Interesting. Thank you.

This will not be as fast as using Cassandra, which is what I do now, but should be a big improvement. I will try it out when I get around to it.

Comment: The link "Parquet's column chunks" is no longer working...

Answer (score 56):

**Update Dec/2018**:

Parquet Format version 2.5 added column indexes.

https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/blob/master/CHANGES.md#version-250

See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-1201 for list of sub-tasks for that new feature.

Notice that this feature just got merged into Parquet format itself, it will take some time for different backends (Spark, Hive, Impala etc) to start supporting it.

This new feature is called Column Indexes. Basically Parquet has added two new structures in parquet layout - Column Index and Offset Index.

*Below is a more detailed technical explanation what it solves and how*.

**Problem Statement**

In the current format, Statistics are stored for ColumnChunks in ColumnMetaData and for individual pages inside DataPageHeader structs. When reading pages, a reader has to process the page header in order to determine whether the page can be skipped based on the statistics. This means the reader has to access all pages in a column, thus likely reading most of the column data from disk.

**Goals**

Make both range scans and point lookups I/O efficient by allowing direct access to pages based on their min and max values. In particular:

1. A single-row lookup in a rowgroup based on the sort column of that
   rowgroup will only read one data page per retrieved column. Range
   scans on the sort column will only need to read the exact data pages
   that contain relevant data.
2. Make other selective scans I/O
   efficient: if we have a very selective predicate on a non-sorting
   column, for the other retrieved columns we should only need to
   access data pages that contain matching rows.
3. No additional decoding
   effort for scans without selective predicates, e.g., full-row group
   scans. If a reader determines that it does not need to read the
   index data, it does not incur any overhead.
4. Index pages for sorted
   columns use minimal storage by storing only the boundary elements
   between pages.

**Non-Goals**

Support for the equivalent of secondary indices, ie, an index structure sorted on the key values over non-sorted data.

**Technical Approach**

We add two new per-column structures to the row group metadata:
ColumnIndex: this allows navigation to the pages of a column based on column values and is used to locate data pages that contain matching values for a scan predicate
OffsetIndex: this allows navigation by row index and is used to retrieve values for rows identified as matches via the ColumnIndex. Once rows of a column are skipped, the corresponding rows in the other columns have to be skipped. Hence the OffsetIndexes for each column in a RowGroup are stored together.

*The new index structures are stored separately from RowGroup, near the footer, so that a reader does not have to pay the I/O and deserialization cost for reading the them if it is not doing selective scans*. The index structures’ location and length are stored in ColumnChunk and RowGroup.

Cloudera's Impala team has made some tests on this new feature (not yet available as part of Apache Impala core product). Here's their performance improvements:

[image: HDFS I/O in Bytes]

and

[image: Scanner CPU time in ms]

As you can see some of the queries had a huge improvement in both both cpu time and amount of data it had to read from disks.

**Original answer back from 2016**:

```
struct IndexPageHeader {
  /** TODO: **/
}
```

https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/blob/6e5b78d6d23b9730e19b78dceb9aac6166d528b8/src/main/thrift/parquet.thrift#L505

Index Page Header is not implemented, as of yet.

See source code of Parquet format above.
I don't see it even in Parquet 2.0 currently.

But yes - excellent answer from Ryan Blue above on Parquet that it has pseudo-indexing capabilities (bloom filters).

If your're interested in more details, I recommend great document on how Parquet bloom filters and predicate push-down work 
https://www.slideshare.net/RyanBlue3/parquet-performance-tuning-the-missing-guide
a more technical implementation-specific document -
https://homepages.cwi.nl/~boncz/msc/2018-BoudewijnBraams.pdf

Comment: Still the same: https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/blob/952c26375eb15c6a27a770f26a6292264b1b7328/src/main/thrift/parquet.thrift#L505

Comment: Tagar, I have not seen any bloom filtering in parquet yet. Could you enlighten your answer, or reference a source?

Comment: @Paul-ArmandVerhaegen bloom filters are always there, normally you don't have to do anything to enable them. I added some references for you.

Comment: @Tagar, thanks for the excellent reading material, but I'm left puzzled. As I understand, you are referring to a framework using the parquet storage format to implement bloom filters. We have also used this before, for example to known whether a guid would have a high probability to be found in a parquet file without have to read the whole parquet file. This is can be stored in the meta data of the parquet file if needed, but is not a support of bloom filtering in parquet itself. See for instance https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-41 for work being done on it.

Comment: Yep, column indexes were just committed to parquet-format two months ago. Parquet readers are implementation-dependent, and as I mentioned in the answer above, "Notice that this feature just got merged into Parquet format itself, it will take some time for different backends (Spark, Hive, Impala etc) to start supporting it."

Comment: I came across this in 2024 - does anyone know the state of ColumnIndexes across the various parquet readers?